# Applying identical Canny to two different images

Tags: python, opencv, canny-operator

I have two images - the images are identical but of different sizes.
Currently I complete a Canny analysis of the smaller image using track bars in an interactive environment. 
I want to have this output created on the second (larger) image - when I apply the same parameters the output is different

I've tried to use `cv.resize` however the output is blurred significantly

Any help is appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please upload those images? Resizing `canny` output should work fine. Just pick right interploation mode for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To archieve comparable results you should resize the bigger image to the size of the smaller one. Image upscaling is "creating" information which isn't contained in your image, that's why you see the blur. Using `interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA` should deliver good results, if you used a camera for images acquisition.